# Efficent way to remove docstring with regex

Tags: python, regex, data-cleaning

I'm trying to create a script to remove all docstrings inside a folder. To do so, I'd like to make a regex as efficient as possible.

I've started with this one:

```py
import re

doc_reg = r'(class|def)(.+)\s+("""[\w\s\(\)\-\,\;\:]+""")'

file_content = '''
"""
Mycopyright (c)
"""

from abc import d

class MyClass(MotherClass):
    """
    Some;
    Multi-
    Line Docstring:
    """

    def __init__(self, my_param):
        """Docstring"""
        self.my_param = my_param

def test_fctn():
    """
    Some Docstring
    """

    return True

def test_fctn():
    some_string = """
    Some Docstring
    """

    return some_string
'''

print(re.sub(doc_reg, r'\1\2', file_content))
```

It works quite well but I'm pretty sure it's possible to make this regex more efficient.

Thanks

Comment: `\b(class|def)(.+)\s+"{3}[\w\s(),;:-]+"{3}` is 345 vs 607 steps (262 fewer)?

Comment: It's just that I'm processing quite many files, it takes a lot of time. As I'm far from being a regex expert I thought there might be a way to improve that.

Comment: Have you benchmarked anything? I would bet that 95% of the processing time is reading the file and/or writing it back to the filesystem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things you can do to make it more efficient and some things you can also do to make it shorter/cleaner.

Original ([607 steps](https://regex101.com/r/2GTcKk/5))

```
(class|def)(.+)\s+("""[\w\s\(\)\-\,\;\:]+""")
```

## Cleaning

You don't need to but a backslash before each character in a set. This may also have almost insignificant improvements in performance since `sre_parse.py` won't call `_class_escape` on line 554 (I'm using Python 3.8.0 as reference).

```
(class|def)(.+)\s+("""[\w\s(),;:-]+""")
```

---

## Efficiency

#### Quantifiers

Use quantifiers for repeated characters ([595 steps](https://regex101.com/r/2GTcKk/7)).

```
(class|def)(.+)\s+("{3}[\w\s(),;:-]+"{3})
                    ^^^              ^^^
```

#### Unneeded Capture Group

Remove unneeded capture groups ([588 steps](https://regex101.com/r/2GTcKk/8))

```
(class|def)(.+)\s+"{3}[\w\s(),;:-]+"{3}
                 ^^                   ^^
```

#### Anchor

Anchor when possible ([345 steps](https://regex101.com/r/2GTcKk/9))

```
\b(class|def)(.+)\s+"{3}[\w\s(),;:-]+"{3}
^^
```

#### Reducing Groups

Combine groups if possible ([337 steps](https://regex101.com/r/2GTcKk/11)) - replacement now becomes `\1`

```
\b(class.+|def.+)\s+"{3}[\w\s(),;:-]+"{3}
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

#### Change Alternation Order

Changing `class|def` to `def|class` can also impact performance if you suspect more `def` than `class` instances ([336 steps](https://regex101.com/r/2GTcKk/12))

```
\b(def.+|class.+)\s+"{3}[\w\s(),;:-]+"{3}
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank for your detailed answer! The funny thing is that even if the last regex (with anchor) has almost 2 fewer steps it's about 50% slower than the one without it. Thanks anyway, your regex is much cleaner than mine!

Comment: @RobinFrcd it depends on the data you're parsing - assuming this is a subset of the data, it can vary.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I'm aware - if you're referencing the regex101 link, steps don't appear on the python version.

Comment: @ctwheels That's news to me. JS doesn't show steps. Your regex is invalid for Python.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus change the delimiter.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus news to me - python steps were finally added to regex101 - changed the links in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it is a very bad idea to parse source code (any, not only Python) using regular expressions. It is very buggy, hard in the future support and doesn't work as expected for any source code block.

Python has a great builtin library named `ast` which provides Python's internal parser which parses source code into tree structures that you can walk passthrough or modify (what we want).

Ok, here is a working example with a bit modified source code for analysis (added function in function to make the example harder =).

`clean.py`

```
import ast

import astor  # read more at https://astor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

parsed = ast.parse(open('source.py').read())

for node in ast.walk(parsed):
    # let's work only on functions & classes definitions
    if not isinstance(node, (ast.FunctionDef, ast.ClassDef, ast.AsyncFunctionDef)):
        continue

    if not len(node.body):
        continue

    if not isinstance(node.body[0], ast.Expr):
        continue

    if not hasattr(node.body[0], 'value') or not isinstance(node.body[0].value, ast.Str):
        continue

    # Uncomment lines below if you want print what and where we are removing
    # print(node)
    # print(node.body[0].value.s)

    node.body = node.body[1:]

print('***** Processed source code output ******\n=========================================')

print(astor.to_source(parsed))
```

`source.py`

```
"""
Mycopyright (c)
"""

from abc import d


class MyClass(MotherClass):
    """
    Some;
    Multi-
    Line Docstring:
    """

    def __init__(self, my_param):
        """Docstring"""
        self.my_param = my_param


def test_fctn():
    """
    Some Docstring
    """

    def _wrapped(omg):
        "some extra docstring"
        pass

    return True


def test_fctn():
    some_string = """
    Some Docstring
    """

    return some_string
```

and console output, I've just printed it to make it easy for the case.

`console.log`

```
python clean.py
***** Processed source code output ******
=========================================
"""
Mycopyright (c)
"""
from abc import d


class MyClass(MotherClass):

    def __init__(self, my_param):
        self.my_param = my_param


def test_fctn():

    def _wrapped(omg):
        pass
    return True


def test_fctn():
    some_string = """
    Some Docstring
    """
    return some_string
```

> I've used standard builtin library [AST - Abstract Syntax Trees](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) for parsing the source code and [astor – AST observe/rewrite](https://astor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to build it back into python executable source code
>
> all in one GitHub Gist https://gist.github.com/phpdude/1ae6f19de213d66286c8183e9e3b9ec1

Comment: That's not directly answering the question, so I can't accept your answer, but that's a fantastic advice you just gave here! Thank you very much mate!